# Dart firstWhere orElse: generic function return type

Tags: dart, generics

The code below defines a generic myFirstWhereFunction with 3 arguments:

- Generic list
- Generic value to search in the list
- Generic default value to return if the searched value is not in the passed generic list

The code:

```
void main() {
  const List<int> intLst = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  print(myFirstWhereFunc(intLst, 4, -1));
  print(myFirstWhereFunc(intLst, 5, -1));

  const List<String> strLst = ['coucou', 'go', 'bold', 'tooltip'];

  print(myFirstWhereFunc(strLst, 'go', 'not exist'));
  print(myFirstWhereFunc(strLst, 'ok', 'not exist'));
}

T myFirstWhereFunc<T>(List<T> lst, T searchVal, T defaultVal) {
  return lst.firstWhere((element) => element == searchVal, orElse: <T> () {
    return defaultVal;
  });
}
```

But this code generates an exception.

One solution is to replace the generic myFirstWhereFunc return type by *dynamic* (code below):

```
dynamic myFirstWhereFunc<T>(List<T> lst, T searchVal, T defaultVal) {
  return lst.firstWhere((element) => element == searchVal,
      orElse: () => defaultVal);
}
```

But is there another way of solving the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that when you do:

```dart
print(myFirstWhereFunc(intLst, 4, -1));
```

there are two possible ways to infer the type of `myFirstWhereFunc`:

- Bottom-up (inside-out): `myFirstWhereFunc` is called with a `List<int>` and with `int` arguments, so its type could be `myFirstWhereFunc<int>`.  This is what you want.
- Top-down (outside-in): `print` has an `Object?` parameter, so `myFirstWhereFunc` could be `myFirstWhereFunc<Object?>` so that it returns an `Object?`.  This is what actually happens and is what you do not want.

Dart ends up with two possible ways to infer the generic type parameter, both seem equally valid at compilation-time, and it picks the one that you happen to not want.  Picking the other approach likely would result in undesirable outcomes for different code examples.  Arguably inference could try both ways and pick the narrower type if one approach leads to a subtype of the other.  I'm not sure offhand if that would break code, but I wouldn't be surprised. (I also suspect that it's been suggested in https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues somewhere...)

Changing `myFirstWhereFunc`'s return type to `dynamic` is a crude workaround to the problem because it makes `myFirsyWhereFunc`'s type no longer inferrable from `print`'s parameter type.

If you split the line up and use a temporary variable, inference can infer `myFirstWhereFunc` independently of `print` and then should do what you want:

```dart
var intResult = myFirstWhereFunc(intLst, 4, -1);
print(intResult);
```